# how to continuosly change code?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am using docker for a nodejs application and I have been able to build the image from an existing nodesource image, I've installed npm, and the source code all copied into supposedly /usr/src/app (which I can't get see, I'm guessing because it's in the image/container). However, I launch the container of the image, mapped it to a port and it successfully ran, but how am I able to just connect with this via an editor and change files? This website is in development and I would like to make changes to it. I've been searching but thoroughly confused.

Here is the node image I've built from

https://hub.docker.com/r/nodesource/trusty/

Also, my container information

d9fe10b0f645        rokes/0.4           "npm start"         10 hours ago        Up 10 hours         0.0.0.0:49160->8080/tcp            evil_hamilton

Would I need to somehow use a volume?

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM nodesource/trusty:latest

ADD package.json package.json

RUN npm install

ADD . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: You need to reinstall your package.json each time you make a modification? Can't you directly work by interpreting the package's code?

Answer (score 0):

Just mount the directory containing your code as a `VOLUME`.

just add in your Dockerfile :

```
VOLUME /path/to/code
```

and then when running your container, use the `-v` option :

```
docker run -d -v /dir/containing/your/code:/path/to/code your_image
```

You can now edit your code on the fly and directly see the changes without having to rebuild and restart your image/container.

Comment: Ok, so this is what my dockerfile originally looked like. Should I then take out the add in here?

FROM nodesource/trusty:latest

ADD package.json package.json

RUN npm install

ADD . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]

Comment: You should replace your "ADD" construction with one VOLUME, because "ADD" means copy a file from my host-machine into container, where "VOLUME" means link folders/files between host-machine and container.

Comment: @arsenalist I see no Dockerfile for the image you linked so I don't know. If you use `VOLUME` you create a mountpoint you use to mount the dir containing your code on, if you make a `ADD` statement you copy the sources in your image. Add the code in your question please.

Comment: @arsenalist To make it clearer : If you use an ADD statement, the code added is copied and becomes a part of your image. If you later change your original code, it won't be changed in your image.

Comment: Ok, so I need to add the VOLUME to the dockerfile (done) AND when I run the container use the '-v' the mount it? One question: Where do I find the /path/to/code?

Comment: Using a bind-mount volume *does not* require the VOLUME Dockerfile directive. These instructions will create a data volume, and then override that data volume with a bind-mount.

Comment: I added the VOLUME in the dockerfile and I ran the container with the -v...it seems to be working now but @LOj1k you are saying that won't work? Should I then change the image again?

Comment: @arsenalist It will if you don't need to reinstall the code you're modifying on each time. Could you answer the question I posted bellow your post?